# How to restore Windows 7 wireless on LAN disconnect

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, thinkpad

When I connect my laptop (Lenovo X201) on Windows 7 Pro SP1 to a wired/LAN connection, it turns off my wireless adapter (Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6250 AGN). On later disconnect, adapter stays turned off, so finds no wireless networks (including established ones), and has to be reactivated using "troubleshooting".

Is there a simple setting to stop this from happening?